# Get collection in blade and check if empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

If I want to display the addresses of a user in a blade file I do it like this:

```
@if(!$user->addresses->isEmpty())
  <ul>
  @foreach ($user->addresses as $address)
      <li >
      {!! displayText($address->toString()) !!}
      </li>
  @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

If addresses would be an array instead of an collection I could shorten the code to:

```
@if(!empty($addresses = $user->addresses))
  <ul>
  @foreach ($addresses as $address)
      <li >
      {!! displayText($address->toString()) !!}
      </li>
  @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

I wonder if there is a better way to check if a collection is empty in a blade file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check if your array is empty before using it in a `foreach`.

But if you need to check if it is empty (to show a message, for example), you can use the [`@empty`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures) tag.

I'd do something like this: (Check also [`@forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops)):

```
<ul>
  @forelse ($addresses as $address)
      <li >
      {!! displayText($address->toString()) !!}
      </li>
  @empty($addresses)
      <li> No addresses... </li>
  @endforelse
</ul>
```

Comment: You can remove  $addresses in @empty($addresses). It's not needed as it's already in the loop context.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it to not print empty `<ul></ul>` but there is an easy way to do this.

You may use `HTML::ul()` to print array of addresses. You may check documentation from [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.html#method_ul) and example usage from [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/195/generating-an-unordered-list-of-items)